# Wrong login on my site and generate error indifferent data I introduce. Site is connected with my database

Tags: php, html, css, web, compiler-errors

Heloo!
Sorry for my Englesh but I am not englesh speacker.
Today I want make a login system conected with database (with xampp help) and some in my code generate a little error. As a refferance I have a [Dani Krossing video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCo6JqGMi30&t=6205s&ab_channel=DaniKrossing), the lastest video about login system with php code (i know, i am in little tutorial hell), and down is my code files. Signup part work good and the problem is at the login part because I introduce on my site on login page login data from my database i introduced on my sign up page and for test i introduce and wrong data and... I have the same error: its about error named "wrong login" (is below with little comment to see whem is error). Now i want some help for fix this problem and make login system to work good. I know is more than normal code section but I want post the file with context to see where is a problem.

-- Database connection

```
<?php

$serverName ="localhost";
$dbUsername ="root";
$dbPassword ="";
$dbName ="gestifino";

$conn = mysqli_connect($serverName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if(!$conn)
{
    die("Connection Fail: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

-- Login script

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    
    $username = $_POST["usersID"];
    $pwd = $_POST["pwd"];

    require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
    require_once 'functions.php';

    if (emptyImputLogin($username, $pwd) !== false) {
       header("location: ../index.php?error=emptyimput");
       exit(); 
    }

    loginUser($conn, $username,$pwd);

} else{
    header("location: ../index.php");
}
```

-- Function script with login functions

```
function emptyImputLogin($username, $pwd) {
    $result;
    if (empty($username) || empty($pwd))
    {
        $result = true;
    } else {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

function uidExists($conn, $username){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE usersID = ?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)) {
        header("location: ../signup/php?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();
    }


    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    /*mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);   
    header("location: ../signup.php?error=none");
    exit();
    */

    $resultdata = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultdata)) {
        return $row;
    }else{
        $result = false;
        return $result;
    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}


function loginUser($conn, $username, $pwd) {

    $uidExists = uidExists($conn, $username);

    if ($uidExists === false) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?error=wronglogin1");
        exit();
    }
    
    $pwdhashed = $uidExists["usersPWD"];
    $checkpwd = password_verify($pwd, $pwdhashed);
    

    if ($checkpwd === false) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?error=wronglogin2"); <------ /* HERE IS A CODE FOR ERROR, I think not work because hashed password not match with clear password, even if i introduce in both forms the same password and same udser ID. User id is primary key and this in database have autoincrement property, but this aspect maybe not metter than password because is the same and i dont make function to hash user id*/
        exit();
    } else if ($checkpwd === true) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["userID"] = $uidExists["usersID"];
        header("Location: ../index.php");
        exit();
    }

}
```

-- HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Autentificare - GestiFino</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
        

    <div class="centered_objects">
        <p class="title">Management System</p>
        <p class="title program">GestiFino - Autentificare</p>
        <form class="form_singin" action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
            <input class="formlogin" name="usersID" placeholder="Introdu ID">
            <input class="formlogin" type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Introdu parola">
            <button class="submitlogin" type="submit" name="submit">Validare</button>
        </form>
    </div>



        <script src="" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I  want make a notice: I have some days in php language and I dont know more exactly what is logical behind the code,but in super general therms i know, because i was more game development with C# language in Unity and this login system is for my little portofolio for my personal idea to do in future.
And now i want to see your solutions to understand what is wrong here and learn how i can make In future more good than that code and to make code without errors.

Comment: Are you sure that `$pwdhashed` value from database is `password_hash`ed generated?

Comment: Yes @Robert, i tryed all possible scenes with hashed password with plane password with another password and i have same error in header. Maybe is write error in code in the middle? Maybe need to make another lines of code?

Comment: I don't think the function can generate another hash @Robert and make this error.

Comment: how do you add users to the database? If you dont use the `password_hash()` function - verification will fail as @Robert pointed out.
offtopic: get rid of all that html IE fallbacks - no mercy for people using IE nowadays ;)